# Write a text into an image

Tags: graphics

I would like to simply put a very short image description over an image I have included using \includegraphics. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\includegraphics{file}\raisebox{5mm}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{-10mm}hello}}
```

will write hello over the image. Adjust the lengths to taste.

Comment: How can I "adjust the lengths to taste"? I am trying to write text at appropriate co-ordinate points using helper grids.

Comment: @envy_intelligence I just meant change the `5mm`to move up or down and the `-10mm` to move left or right. You can use any units you like and unless you are doing automated printing of thousands of these things I'd just adjust "by eye" looking at the final output.